# Why do I get two different answers for electric field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, symmetry, gauss-law

> Consider a long cylindrical charge distribution of radius $R$ with a uniform charge density $\rho$. Find the electric field at distance $r$ from the axis where $r < R$.

I did the problem 2 times, first by integrating electric field and the second by Gauss's Law and I got different answers. The answer key's answer is the same as the one I got by Gauss's Law, so apparently my first method is wrong. How is it wrong?

First method:

$d\vec{E}=\frac{k dQ}{r^2} \hat{r}$

$d\vec{E}=\frac{k (\rho \pi r^2 dr)}{r^2} \hat{r}$

$d\vec{E}=k \rho \pi dr\ \hat{r}$

$\vec{E}=k \rho \pi r\ \hat{r}= \frac{\rho r}{4 \epsilon _0} \hat{r}$, radially away

Second method:

I take my gaussian surface to be the cylindrical shell of length $l$ and radius $r$ away.

$\oint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{A}=\frac{\Sigma Q}{\epsilon _0}$

$\vec{E} \cdot (2\pi rl)=\frac{\rho \pi r^2 l}{\epsilon _0}$

$\vec{E} = \frac{\rho r}{2 \epsilon _0} \hat{r}$

Comment: In the first method, seond equation, $dQ = \rho \pi r^2 dr$ is not right/ This expression didn't fitt with cylindrical geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method is not correct by assuming a shperical symmetric geometry. For an element charge locates on the cylinder $\vec{r}' = (r', \phi', z')$. It contribution to the field point $\vec{r} = (r, \phi=0, z=0)$, $d\vec{E}$ will be along the direction $\hat{n}$ unit vector along the $\vec{r} - \vec{r}'$.

The square distance
$$
   |\vec{r} - \vec{r}'|^2 = r'^2 + r^2 - 2 r r' \cos \phi' + z'^2
$$

Thus the integral expression for eletric field from the whole cylinder.

$$
   | \vec{E}(\vec{r}) | = \int_0^{min(r,R)} r' dr' \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi' \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dz' \frac{\rho \hat{n} \cdot \hat{r}}{r'^2 + r^2 - 2 r r' \cos \phi' + z'^2}.
$$
[image]

Comment: What about for points within the cylinder? (The question stated $r<R$)

Comment: Replace the integral of $dr'$ to upper limit $r$. The ourside part gives no contribution,

Comment: I revised the upper limit to minimum of  $r$ and $R$.